# T(n) for a nested loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

Can someone help me find the T(n), the number of times the inner loop will run as a function of n, for the following loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j /= 2)
        cout << j << endl;
```

Just looking at this i know that the big-O is `O(n*log(n))` but i am also supposed to figure out the `T(n)`

I have ran the code and found the number of times the statement is executed. i have figured out a series but i have not figured out how to simplify it:

```
log_2(n-1)+1+log_2(n-2)+1+log_2(n-3)+1+.......
```

I have tried to use the logarithmic product rule to simplify it to

```
T(n)=log_2((n-1)!2^2))
```

but that does not satisfy the equations.

*edited to explain what i meant by `T(n)`

Comment: What do you mean by "the T(n)"? This isn't standard terminology like Big-O notation is.

Comment: Are you trying to find exactly how many times the loops run?  Worst case?  T(n) means nothing to me either so please explain.

Comment: Let's say you know what `T(n)` is. Then how much more work do you need to do if `n` is increased by 1? Well, you'd have to do the inner loop one more time. The inner loop goes from `i` (which is roughly `n`), to 0, by halving each time. So you get something like `T(n) = T(n-1) + log_2(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

By `T(n)`, I think you mean a function for the number of "fundamental operations" for an input of size `n`. First you have to pick a "fundamental operation". In this case, `cout << j << endl` seems like a reasonable choice.

Let's build up from some simpler examples:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << i << endl;
```

(Since I can't do sigma notation here, I will write `sum(a, b, c)` where `a` is normally written below the sigma, `b` is written above the sigma, and `c` is written to the right of the sigma.)

The analysis of a for loop is based on a summation. We execute each output operation once, so `T(n) = sum(i = 0, n - 1, 1)`. We can prove by mathematical induction that `T(n) = n`.

Since this is identical to your outer for loop, we can write `T(n) = sum(i=0, n, THE NUMBER OF STEPS FOR THE INNER LOOP)`.

To analyze the inner loop, let's start by noting if we count in the opposite direction:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    cout << i << endl;
```

the analysis is the same.

Now let's do something a little more complex:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
    cout << i << endl;
```

We need to count the steps using sigma notation, so we will transform the code a few times while preserving the number of steps executed. In the same way that our previous counting examples have the same number of steps, we can write this as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i *= 2)
    cout << i << endl;
```

I understand the output will be different, but we are only concerned about the number of steps.

We need to make one more transformation since sigma notation always increments by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Now this looks a lot like our first example: `T(n) = sum(i=0, n/2 - 1, 1) = n/2`.

So now we can add the summation of the inner loop to our function:

```
T(n) = sum(i=0, n, sum(j=i, n/2 - 1, 1))
```

The final step is to solve this summation for a closed formula. This is left as an exercise for the reader.